# The difference between PyQt and Qt when handling user defined signal/slot

Tags: pyqt, signals, slot

Well, I am familiar with Qt, but when using PyQt, the syntax of signal/slot really confused me.
When using C++/Qt, the compiler will give you a hint where you are wrong about the signal/slot, but the PyQt default configuration doesn't give a hint about error. Is there a ways or such as debug trigger mode to enable PyQt to display more information?
the Code is as following:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import time

class workThread(QThread):

    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(workThread,self).__init__(parent)
        self.mWorkDoneSignal = pyqtSignal() ## some people say this should be defined as clas member, however, I defined it as class member and still fails.

    def run(self):
        print "workThread start"
        time.sleep(1)
        print "workThread stop"
        print self.emit(SIGNAL("mWorkDoneSignal"))

class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self , parent = None):
        super(MainWidget,self).__init__(parent)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def display(self):
        print "dispaly"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    c = workThread()
    d = MainWidget()
    ##In Qt, when using QObject::connect or such things, the return value will show the 
    ## signal/slot binding is success or failed
    print QObject.connect(c,SIGNAL('mWorkDoneSignal()'),d,SLOT('display()'))
    c.start()
    d.show()
    app.exec_()
```

In C++,the QObject::connect return value will show the signal/slot binding is success or not. In PyQt, the return value is True, but it doesn't trigger the slot.
My Question:
1) Is the signal shoud be a class member or instance member?
2) If QObject.connect 's return value can't give the hint of the binding is success or not, is there other ways to detect it?
   I want to bind the signal/slot outside the signal sender and slot receiver, so I perfer to use the QObject.connect ways. But how can I write this correct, I tried the following ways,both fail.

```
 QObject.connect(c,SIGNAL('mWorkDoneSignal'),d,SLOT('display'))
 QObject.connect(c,SIGNAL('mWorkDoneSignal()'),d,SLOT('display()'))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should really use [new style signals](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) with pyqt. In fact, `QObject.connect` and `QObject.emit` will not even be there anymore [in PyQt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#old-style-signals-and-slots).

```
def __init__(self,parent = None):
    super(workThread,self).__init__(parent)
    self.mWorkDoneSignal = pyqtSignal()
```

This creates an unbound signal and assigns it to a instance variable `mWorkDoneSignal`, wich dosn't really have an effect. If you want to create an signal, then you really have to declare it on the class.

So if you didn't really create a signal here, then why did this call succeed:

```
QObject.connect(c,SIGNAL('mWorkDoneSignal()'),d,SLOT('display()'))
```

The answer lies in the [handling of old style signals](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/old_style_signals_slots.html#pyqt4-signals-and-qt-signals) by PyQt4:

> The act of emitting a PyQt4 signal implicitly defines it.

For that reason when you connect a signal to a slot, only the existence of the slot is checked. The signal itself doesn't really need to exist at that point, so the call will always succeed unless the slot doesn't exist.

> I tried the following ways,both fail.

```
QObject.connect(c,SIGNAL('mWorkDoneSignal'),d,SLOT('display'))
QObject.connect(c,SIGNAL('mWorkDoneSignal()'),d,SLOT('display()'))
```

The first fails because `display` (without parenthesis) isn't a valid slot.
The second succeeds. The reason it doesn't work is because you emit `mWorkDoneSignal`, but what you actually need to emit is:

```
self.emit(SIGNAL("mWorkDoneSignal()"))
```

Using new style signals, there's no way to mess things like this up:

```
from utils import sigint
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import time

class workThread(QThread):

    mWorkDoneSignal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(workThread,self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        print "workThread start"
        time.sleep(1)
        print "workThread stop"
        self.mWorkDoneSignal.emit()

class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self , parent = None):
        super(MainWidget,self).__init__(parent)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def display(self):
        print "dispaly"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    c = workThread()
    d = MainWidget()
    c.mWorkDoneSignal.connect(d.display)
    c.start()
    d.show()
    app.exec_()
```